# Umbraco 10 Site Logo only showing on homepage

Tags: image, umbraco

I currently have a site logo with the element set up on the homepage so that the user can change it, but it's only rendering on my homepage.  How do I get it to show on all pages.  This is my code

```
@{
var siteLogo = Model.Value<IPublishedContent>("siteLogo");
if (siteLogo != null)
{
<img src="@siteLogo.Url()" class="navbar-brand logo">
}
}
```

It's probably something simple I'm missing but I can't work it out.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco CMS provides page inheritance. That means you can create a master template that other pages, like the `Home` page, can use as a default template.

In the Umbraco Backoffice, `Template` section, create `Master.cshtml` that contains your logo and possibly `header` and `footer` of your website.

In the `Home` or any other page you want to have a logo, just set the template to inherit from `Master.cshtml`

```
@inherits Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Views.UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.NameOfPage>
@using ContentModels = YourProject.Models.PublishedContent;
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
```

see [Umbraco Master Template](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/tutorials/creating-a-basic-website/creating-master-template-part-1)

Comment: I have fixed it with this  @if (home.SiteLogo != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(home.SiteLogo.Url))
            {
                <div class="nav-link--home">
                    <a href="/"><img class="logo-image" src="@home.SiteLogo.Url" alt="@home.Sitename"></a>
                </div>
            }